# Problem using Razor after migrating MVC 2.0 to MVC 3.0 RC

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-3

I migrated a MVC 2.0 site to MVC 3.0, using that : [Migrating MVC 2.0 -> 3.0](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#0.1__Toc274034214)

Using ASPX as View Engine works great now...

But I tried to create a Razor view and got that error:

```
The view 'TestView' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched:

    ~/TestView.aspx
    ~/TestView.ascx
    ~/Views/Color/TestView.aspx
    ~/Views/Color/TestView.ascx
    ~/Views/Shared/TestView.aspx
    ~/Views/Shared/TestView.ascx
```

How can I enable razor on that?

I´m using Visual Studio 2010...
Creating a brand new MVC 3 Web Application enables Razor fine!

Thanks

Comment: try adding `ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());` to your global.asax file

Comment: Thats it! Worked fine... Post that answer, so I can accept ! Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding `ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());` to your global.asax file

Answer (score -1):

Please review

In Solution Explorer, delete the reference to System.Web.Mvc (which points to the version 2 DLL). Then add a reference to System.Web.Mvc (v3.0.0.0). Also add a reference to System.WebPages.dll and System.Web.Helpers.dll.