# Webforms porting to Razor MVC error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, transformation, razor

```
The view 'Art' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched

~/Views/Home/Art.aspx
~/Views/Home/Art.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Art.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Art.ascx
```

I've created the view using the `Razor View Engine`. So, the view exists in the `Views` folder under the `Home` folder with the name `Art.vbhtml`

Please tell me how to tell the web application that it needs to render the views using the `Razor View Engine`

**UPDATE:**

[Problem using Razor after migrating MVC 2.0 to MVC 3.0 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146429/problem-using-razor-after-migrating-mvc-2-0-to-mvc-3-0-rc) helped me, but now it is giving this error...

```
Type 'RazorViewEngine' is not defined
```

although, intellisense in the visual studio is showing it and highlighting as a class name as well.

**UPDATE II:**

Nathan Ratcliff's answer helped in removing the error, but now the new error is producing whose details are as under...

```
The view at '~/Views/Home/Art.vbhtml' must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage<TModel>.
```

Nathan can you help me on this as well?

**ANSWER SUMMARY**
For those, who arrive later on this stage, the answer supplied is enough to clear my situation, but I would like to clarify a few things regarding the answer.

I had to perform the following steps to make the Razor Engine running in my application(apart from the answer):

- Added a web.config in the Views folder in the project (Added sections of code supplied in the answer below in the web.config).
- Added a reference for the System.WebPages.dll file in my project.

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?  MVC3 uses the Razor view engine by default.  If you are using 3, are you specifically clearing the view engines collection and only loading the webforms view engine?

Comment: I am using MVC3 and am not clearing any view engine collection. I am trying to run both MVC related pages and web forms in the same website

Comment: You don't need to clear the view engines. You can easily run both if you need to. You'll take a very tiny performance hit on the look up of the views, but it works just fine this way.

Comment: Sorry, bad assumption.  I've got my projects set to Razor by default, but you can select WebForms when you create a project - which means you do need to add it to the view engine collection with ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());

Comment: @BZink, not suggesting you need to clear the collection, I just thought maybe he was.

Comment: Edited answer with suggestion for new issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have this in the compilation section of your web.config

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

and remove the old one.

Also, www.asp.net's recommendations for upgrading from 2.0 -> 3.0

http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading

Edit:

In your views folder, there is a web.config (not the one at the root of your project).

Does it have the razor config sections?

```
    <configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>


    <system.web.webPages.razor>
      <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        </namespaces>
      </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I had referenced the `version=2.0.0.0` in my web.config changed it to `version=3.0.0.0` and it started working. Only that it has started giving another error now. Updated my description above. Please reply to that one as well in your answer.

Comment: How about project references?  Are you referencing the correct version of System.Web?

Comment: `System.Web` is not shown in the references list and when I tried to add it (after your comment) it gave the error that `The website is already referencing the assembly 'System.web'`.

Comment: If you've done everything in the whitepaper listed above and it still isn't working then I'm sorry to say that I am out of ideas without actually being able to see the project.

Comment: I am basically porting a asp.net web forms application to MVC3 application and am having some problems in this. not from MVC2 to MVC3

Comment: I did not have a web.config in my Views folder because I created it manually while adding changes to my existing ASP.Net website. I added the web.config to the Views folder (after your comment), with the text that you have pasted above and it did not work... :(

Comment: That wasn't everything that should be in that file.  Create a new MVC3 project, select Razor as the view engine and then steal the /views/web.config file from that new project.

Comment: Adding the web.config and adding a reference to `%ProgramFiles%\ Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.WebPages.dll` (from the whitepaper you supplied) sorted out the issue. Thanks for your support on this question. BTW, the sections you have added in your answer of web.config are enough to make the Razor engine run. :)